# TypeError: Scheme is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to do a user registration with a Node js app and MongoDB but I have this error:

```
var UtenteSchema = Scheme({           
TypeError: Scheme is not a function
```

There's my model utente.js

```
const { Mongoose } = require("mongoose");
const mongoose = require("./database");

const Utente = mongoose.model("Utente", new Mongoose.Schema({
    email: String,
    nome: String,
    cognome: String,
    password: String,
    admin: String,
  })
);

module.exports = Utente;
```

and there's my database.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect("mongodb+srv://db:password@eonesports.veiykkq.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority", {useNewUrlParser: true});

var conn = mongoose.connection;

conn.on('connected', function() {
    console.log('Database connesso');
});
conn.on('disconnected',function(){
    console.log('Database disconnesso');
})
conn.on('Errore', console.error.bind(console, 'Errore di connessione:'));
module.exports = conn;
```

I'm trying to do a save query to my mongodb atlas online database.

Comment: Well why do you expect `Scheme()` to exist as a function? Where is it supposed to come from?

Answer (score 1):

You only need to import `mongoose` library to create a schema. Your `database` package is not required to create a schema.

In your utente.js paste the below code.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UtenteSchema = mongoose.Schema(
  {
    email: String,
    nome: String,
    cognome: String,
    password: String,
    admin: String,
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Utente", UtenteSchema);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code snippet

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const Utente = mongoose.model("Utente", new Schema({
    email: String,
    nome: String,
    cognome: String,
    password: String,
    admin: String,
  })
);

module.exports = Utente;
```

The difference here is we call `.Schema` and `.model` from the default import `mongoose`

Answer (score 0):

you have exported wrong variable in `database.js` file

it should be the mongoose instance, e.g:

`module.exports = mongoose`

What you have is
`module.exports = conn;`. Meaning the `connection` variable does not have `.Schema` in it, or is not a function as the log stating